# Replace certain combination of characters with another

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In C# I'm trying to replace characters in a string. To be more precise, wherever there is a double quote which is NOT followed, nor preceded, by a comma, I'd like to replace that double quote with a single quote. So, for example:

```
John",123
```

and
    123,"John

are both fine, because there is a comma either before or after the double quote, but:

```
John"Marks
```

is not fine because there is a double quote which is neither preceded not succeeded by a comma, so it should be replaced with a single quote. I.e. it should become:

```
John'Marks
```

I'm struggling to figure this one one... any ideas anyone? Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use look arounds for your search regex:

```
(?<!,)"(?!,)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WmakjT/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!,)` - Negative Lookbehind to assert previous character is not a comma
- `"` - Match a double quote
- `(?!,)` - Negative Lookahead to assert next character is not a comma

Replacement string would be just a single quote `"'"`

**Code:**

```
string repl = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!,)\"(?!,)", "'");
```

Comment: Correct pattern declaration in C# is `@"(?<!,)""(?!,)"` or `"(?<!,)\"(?!,)"`

Comment: Yes thanks Wiktor, that's correct. I have used escape option.